# Uploading files, tempfile and vulnerabilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

In my app users can upload a csv files that I don't directly store anywhere, they're only parsed, so my importer class receive ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object and then I call `#tempfile` on it to access the tempfile and parse it.

Do I still have to worry about any vulnerabilities listed in [the "File Uploads" section of guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#file-uploads)?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're still susceptible to denial of service, if you're parsing inside the web request. Without seeing the code in question, I can't say definitively that you're safe from the path expansion (e.g., "../../some/secret/file") outlined in that note. That said, if all the file handling is done by Rack/ActionDispacth and you're not dealing directly with the path , I suspect that you're safe.

Comment: I pass the params[:file].pathfile to an importer: [ClockworkTomatoImporter](https://github.com/ravicious/tomatostats/blob/77936ccab63f6e04446bfbe5ec030018ecc190e6/app/importers/clockwork_tomato_importer.rb) < [Importer](https://github.com/ravicious/tomatostats/blob/77936ccab63f6e04446bfbe5ec030018ecc190e6/app/importers/importer.rb), [imports_controller](https://github.com/ravicious/tomatostats/blob/77936ccab63f6e04446bfbe5ec030018ecc190e6/app/controllers/imports_controller.rb).

Comment: As for moving parsing out of web request: yes, that definitely something I have to do. Also, some basic protection against parsing very large files.